# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery function is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having a problem with this sample code. When I try to execute someFunc(), I get the error:
Uncaught TypeError: $.twbsPagination is not a function.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.twbsPagination.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

...

<td>
    <button id="button" onclick="someFunc(); return false;">Display Pages</button>
</td>
<div id="pagination-demo"></div>

...
<script>
   function load() {
       $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({  // THIS WORKS.
           totalPages: 35,
           visiblePages: 7,
           onPageClick: function (event, page) {
               $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page);
           }
       });
   }
      
   function someFunc() {
      $.twbsPagination(); // THIS DOESN'T WORK.
   }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried:

```
function someFunc() {
   $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
           totalPages: 10,
           visiblePages: 7,
           onPageClick: function (event, page) {
               $('#page-content').text('Page ' + page);
           }
       });
   }
```

This doesn't work, either. I still get the above Uncaught TypeError. How do I fix this? It just doesn't seem to work when called from the onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage of `jquery.twbsPagination.js` is to provide a selector / list of elements first before calling `twbsPagination({ ... })`.

In short, this usage is incorrect: `$.twbsPagination({ ... })` while this is correct: `$('.your-element').twbsPagination({ ... })`

Comment: I've tried $('.your-element').twbsPagination({ ... }) already. I still get an error.